# How can I generate External IP when creating an ingress that uses nginx controller in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress 
metadata:
  name: helloworld-rules
spec:
  rules:
  - host: helloworld-v1.example.com
http:
  paths:
  - path: /
    backend:
      serviceName: helloworld-v1
      servicePort: 80
  - host: helloworld-v2.example.com
http:
  paths:
  - path: /
    backend:
           serviceName: helloworld-v2
           servicePort: 80
```

I'm making kubernetes cluster and I will apply that cloudPlatform Isolated(not aws or google).
When creating an ingress for service I can choose host url but that is not exist anywhere(that address is not registrated something like DNS server) So I can't access that url. Visiting this IP just gives a 404.
how can I get or configure URL  that can access external browser 
:(...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on how you configure your nginx controller.

You should have a Service configured which is the entry point when accessing from outside see the docs https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress.

So basically you have a Service that points to the ingress controller and this will redirect the traffic to your pods based on Ingress Objects.

Ingress -> Services -> Pods

Since you don't run on aws or google You would have to use externalIp or NodePort and configure the service accordingly

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: ingress-nginx
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: http
  externalIPs:
  - 80.11.12.10
```

And DNS needs to be managed with whatever you have for your domains in order to resolve, or for locally testing you can just edit your /etc/hostnames

Basically in AWS or Google you just create a service with type: LoadBalancer and point your dns records to the balancer address (CNAME for aws and the IP for google)

Comment: Thank you very much! I under stand that! thank you! have nice day!